# Tab Bar controller reload same page again

Tags: iphone

I am making an app of tabbar controller. In which I set login page as a first tabbar. I press login tab and done the login procedure. now when I again pressed first tab login it reload the page and again display the login page. i need to lock page after successful login. same problem in all tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a navigation controller as your tab view, `UITabBar` will set it back the the root controller (the bottom of the stack) when the user taps the corresponding tab.

There are a number of ways to avoid this, one of the simplest being to remove the view controller you no longer need (your login page) from the navigation stack.

Comment: can you told me in brief. I am new in this field

Comment: I would check out Apple's docs for view controllers in general: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457

Comment: But, the key to take away: you need to change the view controller stack(s) to your logged-in viewcontrollers, and remove your login viewcontroller.

Comment: hey but when i pressed again tab continue two times it assign a new array and delete previous one navigation array. It start from FirstViewController

Comment: solved the problem. I set the login success controller snd set the bool whenever pressed tab it first check loginsuccesscontroller if bool is not set than it navigate to firstviewcontroller. thanx